# H-bridge circuit - Smoke

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge

I'm trying to build an H-bridge to run a high-powered motor, but seem to have done something wrong, since it lets out all the magic blue smoke when I engage the logic to turn the motor. In this case, when MOTOR_FORWARD goes high, I blew the Q5 N-channel.

I'm using a TLP521 optocoupler to turn my 3.3 V logic to 12 V, which energizes a 2N2222 for the P-channel MOSFET while also handling turning on the matching N-channel.

A TVS diode (SA14CAHE3/54) is directly between the two motor terminals.

This is my first attempt at building an H-bridge, so any help will be appreciated. I'm a software guy that does simple hardware as a hobby, and this is the most complicated circuit I've done.

[image: PCB]

[image: Schematic]

Comment: If your schematic is correct, note the body-diodes of MOSFETs Q2 and Q4 ... they're always going to be conducting so as soon as Q3 or Q5 turn on, you're shorting your battery.

Comment: Your layout here is pretty bad. Are you using this for PWM, or just occasional switching? And why are you using 120 ohm resistors, especially for R3 and R4? Those are going to pull way more current than necessary from the motor_forward and motor_backward signal lines.

Comment: @hearth I'd like to use it for PWM if possible. The Q2 and Q4 are backwards (oops) which is causing the short (thanks adam-lawrence and nanofarad), but what other changes would you recommend? I don't remember where I got the 120 ohm value from now.

Comment: I would recommend actively driving both high and low, if you're not, instead of using pull-down resistors to turn off. Pull-down resistors are still a good idea, but they should be on the order of a few kΩ, not 120 Ω. And the PCB layout needs to be completely redone if you're doing PWM, there's far too much parasitic inductance everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll have another go at it. This community is awesome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Q2 and Q4 have their source/drain swapped so their body diodes point downward and always conduct. When MOTOR_FORWARD is taken high, Q5 turns on and the power supply is shorted through Q4/Q5.